# can I automate woocommerce email when someone places an order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to send email automatically from my woocommerce website to my address when someone places an order? I've been looking for it for months and still cannot find any answer.

Comment: I thought it already did that? Are you sure that messages are not simply getting lost (either via internal/external spam filters, or by a poor server setup)?

Comment: I've figured out that this is a hosting issue. I managed to tackle it using SMTP plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is in built/ Default features of woocommerce.

In your `wordpress` admin Go to `"WooCommerce -> Setting -> Emails"` and Set your email address there.

Comment: I've figured out that my hosting disables the some features, which affects emails.This is hosting issue.